# Blender 2.80 to Blackmagic Fusion

Tags: export, add-on, camera, workflow, baking

What is the best way to export camera animation from Blender 2.80 to Blackmagic Fusion. There is a script addon published on [BlenderArtists](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-export-camera-to-bmd-fusion/631739/78) which is perfect however it has not been updated for Blender 2.80. Would be awesome if this could be updated. I have tried FBX exporter and it does not give accurate results most notably if there is gaps between key frames in Blender the interpolation is different in Fusion and does not line up in those parts. Is there a way to force Blender to key every frame I have tried the bake option but it does not do every frame.

Comment: Updated the [script for 2.8x](https://gist.github.com/p2or/5560c142fcb14716c6ac490a1d9bfb6e) Could you please test whether it is working as expected?

Comment: Thank you so much aliasguru! Testing now, will let you know.

Comment: @aliasguru There are two issues that I have come across so far.

Comment: @aliasguru First issue is with the export, an error occurs if only the camera is selected and the check box for 'export only selected' is checked. The second issue is that the Fusion comp is not able to be opened by Fusion.
[Image One](https://imgur.com/Ow43B1X).
[Image Two](https://imgur.com/BCLfvWg).

Comment: @p2or I believe Bopstar tried to ping you

Comment: @aliasguru Thanks, sorry for that :)

Comment: I think I fixed both issues @Bopstar It's been a while since I worked with fusion. Otherwise, can you please share one of your blender scenes to test with?

Comment: Tested against Fusion9 - the selection works but there is still this <eof> issue while opening the comp, meaning that the file is not formatted properly (not on my side, I guess they changed the file specifications in newer versions of fusion or there was a bug before) @Bopstar In best case it's just one curly brace which is missing somewhere, all other stuff is written to the disc like before so we just need to figure out what's missing or what's wrong in the comp file exported. Also let's continue chatting over here: https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-export-camera-to-bmd-fusion/631739/81

Comment: Ok @p2or let continue chatting over there. Thanks for all your efforts greatly appreciated.Might be worth asking over here for help to test it also [We Suck Less](https://www.steakunderwater.com/wesuckless/viewforum.php?f=16)